# Is a question about increasing my pain tolerance for electronic muscle stimulation on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, specific-question

I'm considering asking the following question:

> **How can I increase my pain tolerance for electronic muscle stimulation?**
>
> I'm participating in a research study about strength training. As part of the study, the researcher applies an electric shock to my arm while I'm lifting a weight. The researcher said that the shock should only be mildly uncomfortable, but I found it very painful.
>
> Are there any ways I can increase my pain tolerance for these shocks? In particular, as part of the study, I'm lifting weights regularly. Can I expect my pain tolerance to go down as the muscles the shock is applied to get stronger?

Would it be on topic on this site?

Comment: My inclination is to say it's okay albeit a topic I don't think we've had before. What exactly is this research that you're participating in and why the shocks?

Comment: I asked the question here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/how-can-i-increase-my-pain-tolerance-for-electronic-muscle-stimulation I added some more information about what's going on in the study to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote yes! Would love to learn more about this. Has certainly been a relevant recovery technique for me in the past, and I think this would be of general interest.